# Wissenschaft vs Naturwissenschaft: Was sind die Unterschiede?

Tags: meaning, difference

I've seen both words used for "science". I'd like to clarify the differences. I'm guessing `Naturwissenschaft` means "Natural science" like Physics, Biology, etc, while `Wissenschaft` means "general science", including social sciences like "Political science". Is that true or is there no real difference?

(I did actually look for the definitions but the English blogs felt unclear and my German isn't good enough to read pure German dictionaries and dictionaries. I just wanted to make sure I've got the differences right.)

Comment: Your guess is true. Have you tried looking it up in a dictionary?

Comment: like here: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturwissenschaft

Comment: "Wissenschaft" means science in general and "Naturwissenschaft" means natural science, that's correct. But often the shorter "Wissenschaft" is used to refer to "hard science", so to speak, meaning to natural science. The humanities, like disciplines like political science, are considered more "soft science". Refer the idea of the [two cultures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Two_Cultures) by C. P. Snow. Though it's gotten significantly less important over the years, this implicite dichotomy between "serious science" (natural science) and "artsy stuff" (humanities) is still around.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich "It cannot be other than" is a *very* strong claim. Did you never stumble across a so-called "false friend" such as *handy* and *Handy*, to just name one?

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich My argument is that one cannot infer a translation from English to German merely based on the similarity of the words. I would just like to encourage you to change your perspective into  someone who does not know the answer yet. This is the perspective we should take into account when answering questions: I don't know whether the OP was unsure, whether thought this might be false friends. My point is that they _could have been_.

Comment: To put it more directly: the existence of false friends proves that actually, it _can_ be other than... So your claim is plainly wrong.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: "[O]ne cannot infer a translation from English to German merely based on the similarity of the words." This is as strong a claim as my one. Of course, one can draw inferences: to **a certain degree**. This is part of etymology. Sure, peculiarities such as false friends can lead one astray. But in this particular case, why did the OP not look it up? To the rest of your comment: Yes, I admit that my perspective was harsh. But it was only a comment, not an answer, and it was in response to the feeling that ever more users do not want to think about problems themselves.

Comment: I did try looking it up but got some vague answers and my German's not quite enough to read entire German blogs explaining the words

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck: I'd argue it's rather English where *science* is frequently understood to mean just *Naturwissenschaften* (or, maybe in a more abstract way, "measurable" topics), whereas *Wissenschaft* typically has a much wider scope. I'd prefer to provide some examples later on (including things I remember seeing on [academia.se]) in an answer, but unfortunately, someone impatient has already prematurely put this question on hold.

Comment: @RalfFriedl: I think it's not that simple (although the "surprise" may rather be on the English side), and this topic would warrant an answer, hadn't the question been put on hold so rashly.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper From my experience, when the word "Wissenschaft" is used, especially in media coverage, it refers to natural science in the vast majority of cases. As anecdotal evidence, I just looked at the first ten articles found on Google News for the search term "Wissenschaft". Eight of them covered topics from natural science, but used general terms only like "Wissenschaft", "Wissenschaftler", "wissenschaftliche Studie" or the like. The remaining two were about the recent decisions in the Exzellenzinitiative.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich "it cannot be other" - But it is. _Wissenschaft_ is basically anything someone does at a university (like _Literaturwissenschaft_). _Science_ is something that's done via the scientific method (unlike _Literaturwissenschaft_).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In German, the (general) *sciences* are typically coarsely [subdivided](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wissenschaft#Differenzierung) into

- Naturwissenschaften
- Geisteswissenschaften
- Sozialwissenschaften

Thanks to this classification, where *Wissenschaften* appears as a stem in all three hyponyms, people are usually aware that *Wissenschaften* is a hypernym (umbrella term) and that it is not restricted to the *Naturwissenschaften*. There is also no indication of such a restriction in dictionaries (see, e.g., [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Wissenschaft), [Wiktionary](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wissenschaft), [Duden.de](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Wissenschaft)).

This may be different in English, where the stem *sciences* only appears in *natural sciences* (and *social sciences*), but not in *humanities*. The missing stem may be a reason why people do not *think* of humanities as a hyponym of *sciences*. But to discuss in depth the English terms would be out of scope at German Stackexchange.

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the dictionary meanings of the terms, you're correct: "Wissenschaft" means science in general, "Naturwissenschaft" means natural science. But often the more general term "Wissenschaft" is used to refer only to "hard science", meaning natural science.

This can probably be best understood if you look at the idea of the [two cultures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Two_Cultures), that the British scientist and novelist C. P. Snow brought up in 1959. According to that idea, the intellectual life of the western societies was generally split into two cultures - the (natural) sciences on one hand, the humanities on the other hand. Snow described that dichotomy as a major hindrance to solving many problems.

For a long time, many people sort of looked down on humanities and didn't consider them "real sciences". After all, could social sciences, political sciences and so forth really *prove* their hypothesises like physics or chemistry could? Natural sciences were "hard science", verifiable, dependable. That "artsy stuff" that the people over at the humanities building were doing was mostly a matter of opinion and belief, maybe true, maybe not, wasn't it?

Over the decades, the gap got smaller. People learned that the insight in natural sciences has limits as well, and that the humanities has its own tool box of methods to underpin its claims. But, especially in media coverage, "Wissenschaft" is still used to refer to natural science only in many cases. As anecdotal evidence, I checked the first ten articles found on Google News for the search term "Wissenschaft" earlier today. Eight of them covered topics from natural science, but used more general terms like "Wissenschaft", "Wissenschaftler", "wissenschaftliche Studie" only. The remaining two were about the recent decisions in the Exzellenzinitiative which universities get additional money, that to my knowledge includes humanities as well.

(Because this question has been reopended again, I reworked my comments above into an answer.)

Comment: Alles, was Sie hier anführen, mag für _science(s)_ in angelsächsischen Kulturkreisen richtig sein. Das Problem ist nur: Hier sind wir bei _german Stackexchange_, und für den deutschen Begriff _Wissenschaft(en)_ ist das Beschriebene leider nicht korrekt. Im Englischen wird zwischen _natural sciences_ und _humanities_ unterschieden; der Begriff _sciences_ steckt nur im ersten Begriff. Im Deutschen ist das anders: Dort wird klassischerweise zwischen _Naturwissenschaften_, _Geisteswissenschaften_ und _Sozialwissenschaften_ unterschieden ...

Comment: ... Allein schon aufgrund dieser Einteilung wird der Begriff _Wissenschaften_ allgemein als Oberbegriff verstanden. Ich kenne tatsächlich niemanden, der unter dem Begriff _Wissenschaften_ nur die Naturwissenschaften subsumieren würde. Ich habe auch Ihre "anecdortal evidence" geprüft: von den 9 Google-Hits für _Wissenschaft_ sind es nur 2(!), und nicht 8, die sich allein mit Naturwissenschaften beschäftigen, und davon ist eine, nämlich scinexx, die die angelsächsische Perspektive schon im Namen trägt.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Wir müssen hier unterscheiden zwischen der "offiziellen", sozusagen der Wörterbuchdefinition der Begriffe und wie sie im Alltag verwendet werden. Und im Alltag wird "Wissenschaft" deutlich überwiegend als Naturwissenschaft verstanden und verwendet, wie ich es beschrieben habe.

Comment: Das stimmt für den deutschen Begriff _Wissenschaft_ einfach nicht. Übrigens verzeichnen Wörterbücher *vor allem* Begriffe, die im Alltag verwendet werden.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck: Wie häufig etwas verwendet wird, ist eine Frage der Quantität, nicht der Qualität. Daher kann man aus der Häufigkeit, bei der Sie recht haben mögen, nichts über die Qualität herleiten. Wenn Leute über Schwerkraft reden greifen sie vielleicht häufiger zum Begriff Wissenschaft, als wenn sie über den Faust oder die alten Griechen reden. Das gibt aber die Bedeutung des Begriffs dann nicht vor. Die Deutschen reden auch häufiger über Hauskatzen als Großkatzen; dennoch ist der Oberbegriff Katze für beide gleich richtig.